# Returning a bit value from proc?? NullReference Exception was caught?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am doing a test to see if the connection string user ID is a sys Admin.

But my code keeps breaking when i try return the value of the bit?

To do this i use the following stored proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckIfAdmin]
@SQLLoginName nvarchar(50),
@IsAdmin bit OUTPUT

As

SET @IsAdmin = IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin', @SQLLoginName)

Print @IsAdmin
Select @IsAdmin
```

And to retrieve the value i use the following C# code:

```
public bool CheckIfIsAdmin(string procedure, SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(procedure, con);
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                foreach (SqlParameter p in parameters)
                {
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add(p);
                }
                SqlParameter IsAdmin = new SqlParameter("@IsAdmin", SqlDbType.Bit);
                IsAdmin.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add(IsAdmin);
                con.Open();      
                con.Close();             
                MessageBox.Show("Is a admin = " + IsAdmin.Value.ToString()); // this should display 1 or 0 
                return ture
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
                return false;            
            }
        }
```

The Error message:

NullReference Exception was caught.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed the `ExecuteXXXXX`() method.

```
 con.Open();      
 cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); // cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
 con.Close();
```

Comment: It now jumps out at: cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); with the following message: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime.

Comment: Verify the SP parameters type.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't execute between opening and closing the connection.